# MYSQL Fulltext search and ampersand (&) character on AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am running MYSQL 8 on an AWS RDS server and I am having problems doing a full text search that includes the "&" character:

```
select * from my_table where MATCH (`field`) AGAINST("a&b" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I've read in other posts that MYSQL sees the "&" character as a **word separator**, which seems correct as I have tested on "ab&cd" against "ab cd" and it works.

I tried to set in mysql.ini:

```
ft_min_word_len=1
innodb_ft_min_token_size=1
```

and then rebuilding the indexes (using `ALTER TABLE my_table ENGINE=InnoDB`), which did work, however I now get results that include "*someting-b*" and "*a somethings else*", etc. instead of just "a&b".

Ideally I want to keep the min word length to at least 2 to prevent this, but then "a&b" won't be found.

Is there a way to set "&" to not be a separator character as an sql command or in the ini file, as I am limited on AWS RDS?

Comment: Raymond - As I said, I also tested it and the other solutions required recompiling MYSQL so I would say yes they did know the code.

Comment: @RaymondNijland you can get the information about operators used by MySQL in FTS using following query: `show variables like 'ft_boolean_syntax';` As of latest version of MySQL (8+) are: `+-><()~*:""&|@`  (@ is specific for InnoDB)

Comment: @RaymondNijland here is the link from documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_boolean_syntax

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya *"Modifying Boolean Full-Text Search Operators

To change the operators used for boolean full-text searches on **MyISAM** tables, set the ft_boolean_syntax system variable. (**InnoDB does not have an equivalent setting.**) "* [source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-modify-boolean-operators)